# How to have pip recurisvely search directories for packages and dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel, python-packaging

Is pip capable of recursively searching through a file system path and installing a package and its dependencies? For example, given the following file structure (files not shown) `pip install packageA -f C:\packages\` does not work.

```
C:\packages\
C:\packages\packageA\
C:\packages\packageA\1.0.0
C:\packages\packageA\1.0.1

C:\packages\packageB\
C:\packages\packageB\2.2.1
C:\packages\packageB\2.2.4
```

Additionally, can these packages be pure source with a setup.py file? Or do they need to be a binary like wheel or zip files. And finally, is there a way to resolve the dependencies? For example, if packageA requires a version of packageB, can pip get that version of packageB from my folders? Do I need html files indicating where and what things are?

I am aware I can point pip directly to local paths (`pip install C:\packages\packageA\1.0.0`), but I want this to function as if the packages were available in PyPI. For example, if a user types `pip install packageB` or `pip install requirements.txt` and that requirements file contains packages that exist locally but not in PyPI, it would just work. (I could set the local package storage path in a configuration file so the pip command doesn't need the -f argument)

Basically, I want to replicate PyPI functionality using a file system without a webserver (security won't let us run one). Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out. I used a package called [pip2pi](https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi) . This package has a command called dir2pi. I create a directory containing tar.gz files. Each tar.gz file was a Python package created with [this layout](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project). To identify versions, I added a hyphen and then used semantic versioning.

The directory looked like this:

```
C:\packages\package_a-1.0.8.tar.gz
C:\packages\package_a-1.1.0.tar.gz
C:\packages\package_b-2.0.0.tar.gz
C:\packages\package_c-1.0.5.tar.gz
```

Then I ran, `dir2pi C:\packages -S`. This created the necessary HTML files and folder layout. At the root of the folder, a folder called simple was created. The name *simple* appears to be a PEP 503 thing. Inside of simple, the folder structure looked like this:

```
C:\packages\simple\index.html

C:\packages\simple\package_a
C:\packages\simple\package_a\index.html
C:\packages\simple\package_a\package_a-1.0.8.tar.gz
C:\packages\simple\package_a\package_a-1.1.1.tar.gz

C:\packages\simple\package_b
C:\packages\simple\package_b\index.html
C:\packages\simple\package_b\package_b-2.0.0.tar.gz

C:\packages\simple\package_c
C:\packages\simple\package_c\index.html
C:\packages\simple\package_c\package_c-1.0.5.tar.gz
```

This is apparently what a compliant file/folder layout looks like for pip.

Each index.html file contains links to its neighboring files and folders. For example, `C:\packages\simple\index.html` looks like this:

```
<html><head><title>Simple Index</title><meta name='api-version' value='2' /></head><body>
<a href='package_a/'>package_a</a><br />
<a href='package_b/'>package_b</a><br />
<a href='package_c/'>package_c</a><br />
</body></html>
```

`C:\packages\simple\package_a\index.html` looks like this:

```
<a href='package_a-1.0.8.tar.gz'>package_a-1.0.8.tar.gz</a><br />
<a href='package_a-1.1.1.tar.gz'>package_a-1.1.1.tar.gz</a><br />
```

Now with the proper HTML files and folder structure, I told pip to look for packages in the `C:\packages\simple` folder. I did this by editing the pip.ini file (the location varies from system to system) and adding this line:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = file:///c:/packages/simple
```

Alternatively, I could also pass this folder into pip as a parameter like so:

```
pip install --index-url=file:///c:/packages/simple package_a==1.1.1
```

Comment: This sounds better, but what if my packages/ folder contains many subfolders and subsub folders?  Then pip2pi cannot give the correct simple/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Is pip capable of recursively searching…?

No. Either one flat directory or a pre-generated html file that lists files in subdirectories.

> Additionally, can these packages be pure source with a setup.py file?

Yes. `pip` can install source distributions, eggs and wheels.

> And finally, is there a way to resolve the dependencies?

Yes, but they must be accessible. That is, a PyPI-like server (not necessary the PyPI), one flat directory or an html file.

PS. To prevent `pip` to look packages at a PyPI use option `--no-index`.